# Coffeescript require module with arguments, browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, browserify

Without checking my previous code in javascript I can require modules in a nodejs application like so:

```
app = require('./foo')('argstring')
```

I haven't yet, check any of my code bases, but I certainly remember I can pass arguments right after the require.

But I am doing client side application right now and decided to use browserify to have the advantage of using `require` in an client-side js application. (I am using coffeescript this time)

I have a class like so:

```
class Foo
  constructor: (@argstring) ->
  bar: () ->
    console.log @argstring

module.exports = Foo
```

Now I have to use it in my primary coffee file:

```
fap = require('./foo')('some string')
console.log fap // returns undefined
```

Whilst if I do:

```
Foo = require('./foo')
fap = new Foo 'some string'
console.log fap // returns the object correctly
```

While I can, obviously choose to use the instantiation, I prefer not, because it is 1 code more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo = new (require('./foo'))('some string')`

You should be just fine doing this instantiation on one line, you just need to make sure and actually `new` the object, and call the proper constructor method.

Comment: I did that and says, `can't find module './foo'`, but this works:

`new (require('./foo'))('some string)`

Why do you think?

Comment: Good question, I'm not entirely sure. Possibly the order of expression execution is not what we'd expect without the parens.